# Checking statistical significance of regression coefficients in DLM package (R)

Tags: r, regression

My time series is modeled as a random walk plus regression terms:

```
#DLM package
model <- function(u) {
  local <- dlmModPoly(order = 1, dV = c(1e-06), dW = exp(u[1]))
  reg <- dlmModReg(x1, dV = exp(u[2]), addInt = FALSE)
  reg2 <- dlmModReg(x2, dV = exp(u[3]), addInt = FALSE)

  return(local + reg + reg2)
}

init <- c(rep(0, 3))
outMLE2 <- dlmMLE(data, init, model) 
dlmModel <- model(outMLE2$par)
```

Is there a way to get t-statistics and p-values for the estimated regression coefficients?

Comment: Is this a Bayesian model?  You can get Bayesian p-values, but it is not particularly easy.

Comment: The estimation is using dlmMLE, which is the maximum likelihood estimation of this model.

Comment: If you add a small example data set and the resulting parameter estimates  I might be able to extract the desired statistics.  I suggest that your code be able to run and return parameters estimates for the example data set just by me (or someone else) copying your code from this website and pasting it directly into R.